# How to quote a quote within a lecture?

Tags: sentence

If there is an quote in my lecture slide, for example:

“180 years of being a beacon of good practice. Something very precious was lost [when Cadbury was taken over]”
–   Sir Dominic Cadbury

Do I need to put my lecturers name and date in brackets after "Sir Dominic Cadbury
"?

Harvard style reference by the way

Comment: I for one am a bit confused by your question.  Granted, I'm easily confused; nevertheless, I'm uncertain as to what you are after.  Are you preparing a PowerPoint presentation, and one of your "slides" includes the quotation by Sir Dominic?  If so, what does your lecturer (your mentor, perhaps) have to do with the quotation?  You're the lecturer, yes?  Please reword your question.  Perhaps there is a cultural factor I am not privy to.  Are you from the UK, for example?

Answer (score 1):

Generally in citations you just cite the original source, so no. Of course it's good to give some credit in an acknowledgement if you've found sources via an intermediary.

Answer (score 0):

For a lecture slide, put the quote in " marks.

Then at the bottom of the slide put the full original citation, not the original lecturer who pointed it out.  If the lecture itself is the work being quoted, then put the name of the lecturer and the date and title of the lecture instead.

This works especially if it is the only quotation on the page.

If not, put the citation after the quote in parenthesis (Am.J.Nonsense, vol 432, p.77)